# Web-view Pagination in Android

Tags: android, webview, epub

I am developing an Android application that reads eBooks (in `epub` format) and as for now I'm using **Paul Siegeman's epublib library** that is really a very good `epub` reader and I am not able to make **Web-view** `pagination` as per mobile screen. Please Help Me.

Comment: Please check : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the relation between epublib library and webview?